# Open-source software like Pay-Per-Click, Google Adwords?

Tags: google-ads-api, pay-per-click

Does anyone know if there is an open source alternative to the software that Google Adwords uses?

I need to make my own ad-management system that can push out ads and gather CPI/PPC analytics. Has anyone stumbled across such a thing?

Answer (score 3):

You can check out [openx](http://www.openx.com). It's made by the same people of [piwik open source analytics](http://www.piwik.org).